# Merge Objects within an array based on property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i am trying to merge objects within an array based on the property and also add the values into a common field.

I want that if a field is re-occurring 20 times in the array then the common field should some all the values it contains through 20 objects. P.S. the values can differ.

It will be more clear with the below mentioned response.

My sample json is

```
[
{
    "_id": "57ed13ada3a7403e1cf73d0f",
    "id": 213,
    "name": "Services",
    "created_at": "2014-10-12 05:30:03.296711",
    "updated_at": "2014-10-12 05:30:03.296711",
    "priority": 0,
    "tags_weight": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "57ed13ada3a7403e1cf73d0f",
    "id": 213,
    "name": "Services",
    "created_at": "2014-10-12 05:30:03.296711",
    "updated_at": "2014-10-12 05:30:03.296711",
    "priority": 0,
    "tags_weight": 35
  },
  {
    "_id": "57ed13ada3a7403e1cf73fc5",
    "id": 51,
    "name": "Sports",
    "created_at": "2014-10-11 03:22:13.640631",
    "updated_at": "2015-02-16 15:22:19.389636",
    "priority": 20,
    "tags_weight": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "57ed13ada3a7403e1cf73fc5",
    "id": 51,
    "name": "Sports",
    "created_at": "2014-10-11 03:22:13.640631",
    "updated_at": "2015-02-16 15:22:19.389636",
    "priority": 20,
    "tags_weight": 90
  },
  {
    "_id": "57ed13ada3a7403e1cf73c54",
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Free",
    "created_at": "2014-10-11 03:22:11.783557",
    "updated_at": "2014-10-11 03:22:11.783557",
    "priority": 0,
    "tags_weight": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "57ed13ada3a7403e1cf73c54",
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Free",
    "created_at": "2014-10-11 03:22:11.783557",
    "updated_at": "2014-10-11 03:22:11.783557",
    "priority": 0,
    "tags_weight": 90
  },
  {
    "_id": "57ed13ada3a7403e1cf73c82",
    "id": 67,
    "name": "Events",
    "created_at": "2014-10-11 03:22:13.817505",
    "updated_at": "2014-10-11 03:22:13.817505",
    "priority": 0,
    "tags_weight": 2
  }
]
```

I want my output to look something like:-

```
[
{
    "_id": "57ed13ada3a7403e1cf73d0f",
    "id": 213,
    "name": "Services",
    "created_at": "2014-10-12 05:30:03.296711",
    "updated_at": "2014-10-12 05:30:03.296711",
    "priority": 0,
    "tags_weight": 37
  },
  {
    "_id": "57ed13ada3a7403e1cf73d0f",
    "id": 213,
    "name": "Services",
    "created_at": "2014-10-12 05:30:03.296711",
    "updated_at": "2014-10-12 05:30:03.296711",
    "priority": 0,
    "tags_weight": 92
  },
  {
    "_id": "57ed13ada3a7403e1cf73fc5",
    "id": 51,
    "name": "Free",
    "created_at": "2014-10-11 03:22:13.640631",
    "updated_at": "2015-02-16 15:22:19.389636",
    "priority": 20,
    "tags_weight": 92
  },
  {
    "_id": "57ed13ada3a7403e1cf73fc5",
    "id": 51,
    "name": "Events",
    "created_at": "2014-10-11 03:22:13.640631",
    "updated_at": "2015-02-16 15:22:19.389636",
    "priority": 20,
    "tags_weight": 2
  }
]
```

It can be observed that in my desired array, i have merged the fields with common name, as well as i have added the tags_weight of each unique object based on its occurrence in the array.

Comment: if the name field of two objects are different then how do you want them to merge?

Comment: actually the merge will be based on `name` field, and i want to add `tags_weight` of every object which has the same value for  `name` key in their objects.

Comment: what did you try ? ]

Comment: what do you want to do with conflicting non-numeric fields?

Comment: i am  struck with how to begin. I am unaware of how to split the array and consider each object as a different entity and iterate over all of them at a single time.

Comment: i am mainly bothered with name and tags_weight, and not need to compute over other fields.

Comment: this will be helpful for starting https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: In your exemple you have removed all **sports** item and duplicated  **services** one. If you want be answered give us an expected output which is valid